# The /etc/issue file gets cut all the way through the 18th line

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tty

I have bought an SSD to replace my old HDD to get my laptop(lenovo thinkpad x220) faster, and made up a fresh installation of Arch Linux with an i3wm and no dm(tty only). I have had a nice ASCII art on my HDD and wanted to make the same one on an SSD. Though the /etc/issue file is the same as I had, the file gets cut to 18th line. I wonder if someone knows what is the boot process and what can give such behavior. Wanted to mention that TTY doesn't display some unicode chars, like `░▒▓`though it used to before(somehow).

Comment: Do you mean the OS (or the filesystem) truncates the file itself? Or it just doesn't print the whole file when you think it should? Is `/etc/motd` printed? Is it printed well?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think the os truncates the stdout when printing this file out. The /etc/motd gets printed (yet without any special symbols support). I don't get any errors when booting and everything else works fine.